# How to count longest uninterrupted sequence in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have `pd.Series` like below

```
s = pd.Series([False, True, False,True,True,True,False, False])    

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```

I want to know how long is the longest `True` sequence, in this example, it is 3.

I tried it in a stupid way.

```
s_list = s.tolist()
count = 0
max_count = 0
for item in s_list:
    if item:
        count +=1
    else:
        if count>max_count:
            max_count = count
        count = 0
print(max_count)
```

It will print `3`, but in a `Series` of all `True`, it will print `0`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use a the series itself to mask the cumulative sum of the negation.  Then use `value_counts`

```
(~s).cumsum()[s].value_counts().max()

3
```

**explanation**

1. `(~s).cumsum()` is a pretty standard way to produce distinct `True`/`False` groups

   ```
   0    1
   1    1
   2    2
   3    2
   4    2
   5    2
   6    3
   7    4
   dtype: int64
   ```
2. But you can see that the group we care about is represented by the `2`s and there are four of them.  That's because the group is initiated by the first `False` (which becomes `True` with `(~s)`).  Therefore, we mask this cumulative sum with the boolean mask we started with.

   ```
   (~s).cumsum()[s]

   1    1
   3    2
   4    2
   5    2
   dtype: int64
   ```
3. Now we see the three `2`s pop out and we just have to use a method to extract them. I used `value_counts` and `max`.

---

**Option 2**
Use `factorize` and `bincount`

```
a = s.values
b = pd.factorize((~a).cumsum())[0]
np.bincount(b[a]).max()

3
```

**explanation**
This is a similar explanation as for option 1.  The main difference is in how I a found the max.  I use `pd.factorize` to tokenize the values into integers ranging from 0 to the total number of unique values.  Given the actual values we had in `(~a).cumsum()` we didn't strictly need this part.  I used it because it's a general purpose tool that could be used on arbitrary group names.

After `pd.factorize` I use those integer values in `np.bincount` which accumulates the total number of times each integer is used.  Then take the maximum.

---

**Option 3**
As stated in the explanation of option 2, this also works:

```
a = s.values
np.bincount((~a).cumsum()[a]).max()

3
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: Man ,this is great :-)

Comment: @piRSquared Adding a python groupby :-) cheers :-), learn a lot from yours , thank you Sir !

Comment: @piRSquared, thanks and learnt a new trick of using (~a).cumsum()

Comment: @piRSquared, how do I know where the longest sequence of trues occur?

Comment: How could this code be modified to find the longest uninterrupted sequence of, say, a specific integer value?

Answer (score 5):

I think this could work

```
pd.Series(s.index[~s].values).diff().max()-1
Out[57]: 3.0
```

Also outside pandas' we can back to python groupby

```
from itertools import groupby
max([len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(s.tolist())])
Out[73]: 3
```

Update :

```
from itertools import compress
max(list(compress([len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(s.tolist())],[key for key, group in groupby(s.tolist())])))
Out[84]: 3
```

Comment: This is very clean.

Comment: @wen, nice use of s.index[~s]

Comment: Maybe I need to pay more time to learn python standard library.

Comment: If all element is `False` it will return `8`, so the code should be `max([len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(s.tolist()) if key])`

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: As piRSquared mentioned, my previous solution needs to append two `False` at the beginning and at the end of the series. piRSquared kindly gave an answer based on that.

```
(np.diff(np.flatnonzero(np.append(True, np.append(~s.values, True)))) - 1).max()
```

---

My original trial is

```
(np.diff(s.where(~s).dropna().index.values) - 1).max()
```

(**This will not give the correct answer** if the longest `True` starts at the beginning or ends at the end as pointed out by piRSquared. **Please use the solution above given by piRSquared.** This work remains only for explanation.)

**Explanation:**

This finds the indices of the `False` parts and **by finding the gaps between the indices of `False`, we can know the longest `True`**.

- `s.where(s == False).dropna().index.values` finds all the indices of `False`

  ```
  array([0, 2, 6, 7])
  ```

We know that `True`s live between the `False`s. Thus, we can use
`np.diff` to find the gaps between these indices.

```
    array([2, 4, 1])
```

- Minus 1 in the end as `True`s lies between these indices.
- Find the maximum of the difference.

Comment: Umm nice solution

Comment: Agreed this is nice.  However, if you have the longest `True` sequence at the beginning or the end of the array, your diff will not catch it.  You need to append `False` to the ends, then do it.  Also, you don't need `s == False`, `~s` will do.

Comment: This is how I would have done it.  Feel free to add it to your answer as it is the same concept, only if you want to (-: `(np.diff(np.flatnonzero(np.append(True, np.append(~s.values, True)))) - 1).max()`  Though I'd suggest formatting nicer.

Comment: @piRSquared thank you for offering the solution to this. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use (inspired by @piRSquared answer):

```
s.groupby((~s).cumsum()).sum().max()
Out[513]: 3.0
```

Another option to use a lambda func to do this.

```
s.to_frame().apply(lambda x: s.loc[x.name:].idxmin() - x.name, axis=1).max()
Out[429]: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code was actually very close. It becomes perfect with a minor fix:

```
count = 0
maxCount = 0
for item in s:
    if item:
        count += 1
        if count > maxCount:
            maxCount = count
    else:
        count = 0
print(maxCount)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how to do it with pandas but what about using `itertools.groupby`?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series([False, True, False,True,True,True,False, False])
>>> max(sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(s) if k)
3
```