# Get maximum occurance of one specific value per row with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, row, find-occurrences

I have the following dataframe:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7  8  9
0  0   0   1   0   0   0   0  0  1
1  0   0   0   0   1   1   0  1  0
2  1   1   0   1   1   0   0  1  1
...
```

I want to get for each row the longest sequence of value 0 in the row.
so, the expected results for this dataframe will be an array that looks like this:

```
[5,4,2,...]
```

as on the first row, maximum sequenc eof value 0 is 5, ect.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897265/how-to-count-longest-uninterrupted-sequence-in-pandas) post and tried for the beginning to get this for the first row (though I would like to do this at once for the whole dataframe) but I got errors:

```
s=df_day.iloc[0]
(~s).cumsum()[s].value_counts().max()
```

> TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the
> inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
> the casting rule ''safe''

when I inserted manually the values like this:

```
s=pd.Series([0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1])
(~s).cumsum()[s].value_counts().max()

>>>7
```

I got 7 which is number of total 0 in the row but not the max sequence.
However, I don't understand why it raises the error at first, and , more important, I would like to run it on the end on the while dataframe and per row.

**My end goal: get the maximum uninterrupted occurance of value 0 in a row.**

Comment: Perfromance is important?

Comment: @jezrael not so much but I'm always open to hear more solutions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the job.

the function `longest_streak` will count the number of consecutive zeros and return the max, and you can use `apply` on your df.

```
from itertools import groupby
    def longest_streak(l):
      lst = []
      for n,c in groupby(l):
        num,count = n,sum(1 for i in c)
        if num==0:
          lst.append((num,count))

  maxx = max([y for x,y in lst])
  return(maxx)

df.apply(lambda x: longest_streak(x),axis=1)
```

Comment: I have tried this on a dataframe and got an error for specific row :  ~~~Input In [43], in longest_streak(l)
      6     if num==0:
      7         lst.append((num,count))
----> 8 maxx = max([y for x,y in lst])
      9 return(maxx)

ValueError: ('max() arg is an empty sequence', 'occurred at index 684')~~~ . Do you know why that happens? I can tell that this row has only values 1.

Comment: can u share an example?

Answer (score 3):

Vectorized solution for counts consecutive `0` per rows, so for maximal use `max` of DataFrame `c`:

```
#more explain https://stackoverflow.com/a/52718619/2901002
m = df.eq(0)
b = m.cumsum(axis=1)
c = b.sub(b.mask(m).ffill(axis=1).fillna(0)).astype(int)
print (c)
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  1  2  0  1  2  3  4  5  0
1  1  2  3  4  0  0  1  0  1
2  0  0  1  0  0  1  2  0  0

df['max_consecutive_0'] = c.max(axis=1)
print (df)
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  max_consecutive_0
0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1                  5
1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0                  4
2  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1                  2
```

Comment: your solutions are always so elegant. You should write a pandas guide book :)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df = df.T.apply(lambda x: (x != x.shift()).astype(int).cumsum().where(x.eq(0)).dropna().value_counts().max())
```

`OUTPUT`

```
0    5
1    4
2    2
```

Comment: You need to add a condition that the value is 0